# Show that $S^2=G$.

Tags: group-theory

I try to solve a question from Grove's Algebra book. The question is that:

Suppose $S$ is a subset of a finite group $G$, with $|S| > \dfrac{|G|}{2}$. If $S^2$ is defined to be $\{xy:x, y \in S\}$ show that $S^2 = G$

Solution should be easy but i couldn't solve it. Thanks for your help

Comment: For any $g \in G$, $|S^{-1}g|= |S|>|G|/2$ so there exists $h \in S \cap S^{-1}g$.